# Edit and delete button on each row for table data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, html-table

I'm doing a movie library as a school assignment and have list of movies from a database table that I want to have a edit and a delete option next to on each row.

I want to use a edit/delete links for it. Like:

```
"<a href='moviestorage.php?edit=" . $id . "'>Edit</a>"
```

But I'm not sure how I can fish up the id for each movie so that it's deleted from the database. What's the query that I should write? Do I need to have a separate delete.php file?
I´m a very newbie so bear with me:)
Below you can see the code that I've done.

```
 <?php 

        require 'connect.inc.php';

//This feels incomplete... I´m trying here to fish the ID...
        $id = "SELECT id from movies";
        $query = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE id='$id'";


        $query = "SELECT * FROM movies, categories WHERE movies.genre_id = categories.genre_id";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if (!$result) die ("Database access failed:" .mysql_error()) ;

        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        echo '<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Release year</th><th>Genre</th><th>Director</th><th>Update</th><th>Delete</th></tr>';

        for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . mysql_result($result,$j,'title') . '</td>' ;
        echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result,$j,'release_year') . '</td>' ;
        echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result,$j,'genre') . '</td>' ;
        echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result,$j,'director') . '</td>' ;
        echo '<td>'."<a href='edit_movie.php?edit=" . $id . "'>Edit</a>".'</td>' ;
        echo '<td>'."<a href='delete.php?delete=" . $id . "'>Delete</a>".'</td></tr>' ;

        }
        echo '</table>'; 

        include 'add_movie.php';
    ?>
```

Comment: I surely hope there's a confirmation dialog on `delete.php`... There are user-agents known to 'pre-fetch' pages for results. ALways do alterations by `POST`, `GET`'s aren't supposed to alter data (although they can of course show you the form to `POST` later).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use a form for every row with a delete and edit button and a hidden field with the ID. You can then post that form to the right script and determine the action to take there.

If you have to use a link to delete an item, at least have the link lead to another confirmation page with a form that the user has to submit and that posts to your delete script.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Yes maybe I should do that! Should I put the hole table, all fields in a form? Or maybe the later option is better, have the link lead to delete.php where there is a confirmation delete form... @jeroen

Comment: @Karolina I would use one form per entry / movie, not one form for all fields. And a confirmation step is always a good idea regardless of the previous step (button or link).

Comment: Hi again, so I just tried to echo out a form just for the delete button and put value="' . mysql_result($result,$j,'id') . '" I don´t know how to fetch the id and this didn´t work. I worked so long with the code that I posted here and if I have to change everything to a form I´m not sure how to do it. So I thought I could put a form just for the buttons edit and delete and use the value="' . mysql_result($result,$j,'id') . '" for it . Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you have to **edit and delete** on new page than you can put hyperlink this way

```
  echo "<a href=\"edit.php?id=".mysql_result($result,$j,'id')."\"><strong>EDIT</strong>";

  echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=".mysql_result($result,$j,'id')."\"><strong>delete</strong>";
```

and for **conformation** for delete you can use this on delete link

```
  echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=".mysql_result($result,$j,'id')."\" onclick=\"return confirm('You want to delete your own account???');\"><strong>delete</strong>";
```

than get the **id** on next page using

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
```

hope it will be usefull for you

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I just tried your code but can´t get it to work:( I managed to solve the delete button which I did by doing a form with hidden fields. But I´m thinking I wanna do the link for the edit option and that link is leading to the edit form page.I just don´t know how to get the choosen ID to follow to the edit page so that the data from the table fields will be filled out in the edit form. I´m going crazy as I can´t solve this:(

Comment: its very easy first get id through $id=$_GET['id']; than fetch the sql result in $result=mysql_query ("select * from table_name where id='$id'") and using while($row = musql_fetch_assoc($result)){ $id = $row['id']} than echo the result in form where you have to use <input name='id' type='text' value="<?php echo $id;?>"..  now hope its use for you..

Answer (score 0):

If you need a simple and effective solution, use datatables. :)
please search in google. spent some time to study how to implement it, it will save a lot of time in future.